# Compress all files of a certain type in a folder using python and tar

Tags: python, glob, tar

How can create a compressed file including all files of a certain extension while keeping the folder structure of the original directory?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create an intermediate file that lists all the files that should be in the compressed file.
We can use the `glob` module for this purpose:

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path

list_of_files = glob.glob("TOP_LEVEL_FOLDER/**/*.MY_EXTENSION",recursive=True)

with open("FILE_THAT_LISTS_ALL_FILES","w") as f:
    for path_to_single_file in list_of_files:
        path = Path(path_to_single_file).absolute()
        f.write(str(path)+"\n")
```

`glob.glob()` creates a list of all relevant files. With the `recursive=True` option, the `**` matches arbitrary sub-directories. This means that this command looks into all the folders recursively.
With the `Path(path_to_single_file).absolute()` command, we make sure that the path is absolute instead of relative, meaning that it does not matter if the intermediate file is moved.

The second step is using `tar` to create the compressed file. With the `-T` option we can specify a file that contains a list of files we want to compress, i.e. our intermediate file.

```
tar -czvf FINAL_DIRECTORY_WITH_ALL_FILES.tar.gz -T FILE_THAT_LISTS_ALL_FILES
```